# Are the results guaranteed to be retrieved in order when using multiprocessing.Pool.map()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

When using `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` are the results guaranteed to come in order, even if `func()` takes a variable amount of time to finish? *(i.e. the 2nd worker could finish before the 1st worker, etc...)*

```
def func(arg):
    # stuff that takes random time to complete ...
    return arg

args = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
results = pool.map(func, args)
print(results)
```

In this example, is it guaranteed that the results will be printed as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? If not, how could I go about making sure that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the `multiprocessing.Pool.map` method, the result will always follow the order of corresponding items in the given iterable, which is why this method would block until all child processes have completed.

Comment: Would the same thing also happen if I were to call it using `results = [pool.apply(func, args=(x,)) for x in range(1,5)]` instead of `map`?

Comment: By using the `apply` method you certainly guarantee the resulting order since every call to `apply` blocks until the child process finishes, but then you would not get any benefit from parallel processing since child processes then simply run sequentially.

Comment: oh one final question. If i were to call map with args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], but keep the pool size at 4, then whichever worker finished their task first would be the one to handle 5 - is that correct?